# Prove whether $f(n)$ is $O$, $o$, $\Omega$, $\omega$ or $\Theta$ of $g(n)$ for given $f$ and $g$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

> Prove whether $f(n)$ is $O, o, Ω, ω$ or $Θ$ of $g(n)$.
>   $$f(n)=\log n2^n,g(n)=2^{2\log n}$$
>   Assume any log. given in the problem is base $2$.

Alright so here's what I've got
$$f(n)=\log n2^n=\log n+\log2^n=\log n+n\log2=\log n+n$$
$$g(n)=2^{2\log n}=2^{\log n^2}=n^2$$
Now from here I can do $f(n)/g(n)$:
$$\frac{\log n+n}{n^2}$$
I then applied L'Hôpital's rule, and found the derivatives. This is where it gets fuzzy for me$\ldots$
$$\frac{1/(n\ln 2)+1}{2n}$$
I do not know how to progress from here, I know I'm close, though (if I derived correctly.)

Comment: You have differentiated the ratio correctly. You should be able to take the limit as $n\to \infty$ now (hint: what does the numerator approach, and what does the denominator approach? As a first step, make sure you know what $1/(n\ln 2)$ approaches.).

Comment: So since ... 1/ (n ln(2) would continue to get smaller approaching 0 the entire numerator would approach 1? and the denominator would approach infinity? and since the bottom grows faster the equation as a whole approaches 0?

Comment: Pretty much! If the numerator approaches $1$ and the denominator approaches $\infty$, then the overall ratio approaches $0$. Thus the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to do it: $\log n<n$ for sufficiently large $n$, so
$$\frac{\log n+n}{n^2}<\frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac2n$$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2n=0$. Thus $f(n)=o(g(n))$.

Comment: Alright so I get the logic on how you got to 2/n, but I'm a real beginner. Could you explain how proving the lim for 2/n lets you find the answer?

Comment: @Brownie By definition, $f(n)=o(g(n)) iff $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$. Both functions here are also positive for $n>1$, which means that substituting $n$ for $\log n$ is taking an upper bound on the original ratio. The squeeze theorem then allows us to conclude that the limit is 0.